# In a Web API class, what's the purpose of having or not having a "Http" tag for each method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

What's the difference between:

```
[HttpDelete]
public void deleteNotification(int userId, int notificationId)
{
    Home.DeleteNotification(notificationId, userId);
}
```

and

```
public void deleteNotification(int userId, int notificationId)
{
    Home.DeleteNotification(notificationId, userId);
}
```

Should you use these tags or not? Why or why not?

Comment: They're called Attributes. It usually helps to find and use the correct name for language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are called HTTP methods, from the [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection):

> HTTP Methods. The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute:
>
> 1. AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
> 2. Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> 3. If none of the above, the method supports POST.

Hence, as long as your method has either attribute `[HttpDelete]` or prefix `delete` in your action, it still works out.

Comment: thanks! I see how it works now. as for good practice, I'm going to always use the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first action will only accept a request with the DELETE method, while the second will accept a request with any method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS or PATCH).

Your action will work for what you use it for either way, it's mostly important for how it should handle incorrect requests. Sometimes there are bad bots/scripts that scan sites for vulnerabilities by doing things like taking any URL they can find and send stuff to it. If the action only accepts a single request method, then most garbage requests will return a HTTP 404 instead of causing an exception (or worse) because of bad input values.